# Makefile include makefile from different directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two makefiles, `directoryA/Makefile` and `directoryB/Makefile`.

`directoryA/Makefile` depends on targets in a rather large and complex `directoryB/Makefile`.

I could do a recursive make

```
$(MAKE) -C directoryB
```

But that is undesirable for [several reasons](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). Two big reasons: I make have to execute the makefile several times, and `make` can't correctly know when rebuilding a target is necessary.

I would like to use the `include` directive. The problem is twofold:

1. The targets in `directoryB/Makefile` are all defined relative to that Makefile.
2. Many commands depend on the working directory being `directoryB`.

Recursive make solves both of these problems, but with big disadvantages (mentioned earlier). Is there a way to solve both problems when using `include`?

Comment: Not without rewriting at least one of the makefiles.  Non-recursive makefiles have to be created from the beginning to understand that they're non-recursive.

Comment: Do the targets/commands in `directoryA/Makefile` likewise depend on the working directory being `directoryA`?

Comment: @Beta, currently yes, but `directoryA/Makefile` is less so. I suppose I could rewrite that one to be able to be included, and then have `directoryB/Makefile` include it.

Comment: @MadScientist, true...what should I do to rewrite them? Is there a way to get the location of the current `Makefile`? Is that the best way to do it.

Comment: @MadScientist, from your suggestion, I have tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727580/writing-a-makefile-to-be-includable-by-other-makefiles) solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing `directoryA/Makefile`, but another alternative is to have it `include directoryB/Makefile`, then

```
cd directoryB
make -f ../directoryA/Makefile
```