# Writing a Makefile to be includable by other Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Background**

I have a (large) project A and a (large) project B, such that A depends on B.

I would like to have two separate makefiles -- one for project A and one for project B -- for performance and maintainability.

Based on the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663753/makefile-include-makefile-from-different-directory#comment34524053_22663753) to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663753/makefile-include-makefile-from-different-directory), I have decided to entirely rewrite B's makefile such that A's makefile can `include` it. This will avoid the evils of recursive make: allow parallelism, not remake unnecessarily, improve performance, etc.

---

**Current solution**

I can find the directory of the currently executing makefile by including at the top (before any other includes).

```
TOP := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

I am writing each target as

```
$(TOP)/some-target: $(TOP)/some-src
```

and making changes to any necessary shell commands, e.g. `find dir` to `find $(TOP)/dir`.

While this solves the problems it has a couple disadvantages:

1. Targets and rules are longer and a little less readable. (This is likely unavoidable. Modularity has a price).
2. Using `gcc -M` to auto-generate dependencies requires post-processing to add `$(TOP)` everywhere.

Is this the usual way to write makefiles that can be `include`d by others?

Comment: Using `-MMD -MP` you wouldn't need post-processing at all. I suggest you show us your makefiles.

Comment: @Chnossos, could you elaborate on `-MMD -MP`?

Comment: `-MMD`will generate `.d` dependency files for each `.o` file with rules for user header files. `-MP` instructs CPP to add a phony target for each dependency other than the main file to work around errors make gives if you remove header files without updating the Makefile to match. ([__Source__](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)) All you have to do is to write your makefile accordingly to handle these two options.

Answer (score 0):

If by "usual" you mean, "most common", then the answer is "no".  The most common thing people do, is to improvise some changes to the includee so the names do not clash with the includer.

What you did, however, is "good design".

In fact, I take your design even futher.

I compute a stack of directories, if the inclusion is recursive, you need to keep the current directories on a stack as you parse the makefile tree.  `$D` is the current directory - shorter for people to type than `$(TOP)/`,

and I prepend *everything* in the includee, with `$D/`, so you have variables:

```
$D/FOOBAR :=
```

and phony targets:

```
$D/phony:
```